# Polynomial operator eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional complex vector space and let $A:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow {\rm End}(V)$, i.e. $A(z):V\rightarrow V$ is a linear operator for all values of $z\in\mathbb{C}$.

I was told the following result by one of my professors:

Suppose $A(z)$ is an operator-valued polynomial of degree $n$, i.e. 
$$
A(z)=\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n A_k z^k
$$
where $A_k:V\rightarrow V$ are linear operators. Let $v$ be an eigenvector of $A(z)$ at $n$ distinct points, that is
$$A(z_i)v=f(z_i)v$$
for some $\{z_1,z_2,\dots,z_n\}$ and $f(z_i)\in\mathbb{C}$ $\forall i=1,2,\dots,n$. Then $v$ is an eigenvector of $A(z)$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$.

No proof was given and I'm actually very unsure of how to prove this. Some tips or even a link to a complete proof would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: You may use Lagrange polynomial (interpolation) to reconstruct $A(z)$ from its values at $n+1$ points (not $n$). Then use the fact that $v$ is an eigenvector to each of the $A(z_i)$, $i=0,...,n$.